# Video is not playing from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I have video uploaded in server url and pass the URL to `MPMoviePlayerController` to play the video automatically but the video is not playing and I'm getting black page. When I using the local video then it's playing.

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"server.net/projects/media/videos/023.mp4"];

 NSLog(@"Magento url is %@", fileURL);

 moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

 [[moviePlayerController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(100,200, 600, 500)];

 [moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:YES];

 [moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];

 [[moviePlayerController backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

 [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];


 [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

Comment: you URL is broken and doesn't lead to video file

Comment: no. The video is playing in the browser

Comment: if it's you local enviroment, then ok, doesn't work for me

Comment: does it work now for you with http://?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the reason why player doesn't load the video because you should add `http://` at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>


//MPMoviePlayer
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov"];
    NSLog(@"Magento url is %@", fileURL);

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
    [[moviePlayerController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    [moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
    [[moviePlayerController backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

    [moviePlayerController play];
```